# Why $xb^x = a$ cannot be solved by arithmetic steps? (a formal explanation)

Tags: arithmetic

How do I solve the following equation? I understand it is not possible with regular arithmetic steps:

$$xb^x = a$$

Provided $b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $a \in \Bbb{R}$. What would be the formal explanation telling this cannot be solved by regular arithmetics, and what would be a good way to solve it?

Comment: Just a nitpick - this can't be solved _in general_, since it clearly can be solved for some specific choices of $a,b$. Also, would you be so kind as to specify what you mean by "regular arithmetic"?

Comment: related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135911/how-to-prove-lamberts-w-function-is-not-elementary

Comment: Regular arithmetic steps to solve an equation (i.e. apply the same operations -except mul/div by zero- at both sides of the equation)

Comment: Would using logarithms be allowed as that may be a way to get an isolation of x?

Comment: with the so-called Lambert we get $$x={\frac {{\rm W} \left(\ln  \left( b \right) a\right)}{\ln  \left( b
 \right) }}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation as
$$
x\,e^{(\log b)x}=a.
$$
Multiply the equation by $\log b$:
$$
(\log b)x\,e^{(\log b)x}=a\log b.
$$
The [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $W(z)$ is defined as the inverse of $z\,e^z$:
$$
(\log b)x=W(a\log b).
$$
Finally
$$
x=\frac{W(a\log b)}{\log b}.
$$

Comment: Aaaah but does $W$ have an algebraic expression somehow? Or is just defined like that (as $Erf$ is defined as the antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$)?

Comment: $W$ is a trascendental function. Unlike the error function, it is elementary, since it is the inverse of an elementary function.